# MySQL DATE and BIGINT with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

Dear All, 
I am working on a Java script capable of loading historical market data from files to MySQL tables, where each data record contains 'date' and 'timestamp' field. A usual record is represented as:

01/11/2010,10:00:00.007,P,210.8,210.86,6,2,R,,2486662,P,P,,0,,N
01/11/2010,10:00:00.577,W,210.51,211.61,1,1,R,,2487172,W,W,,0,,N

where the first column represents 'date' and the second represents 'timestamp' (with a millisecond granularity). Since MySQL do not support millisecond granularity, I am using BIGINT (long) representation of the 'timestamp' field.

Currently the load query is as follows:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to file' 
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(@date, @time, remaining columns ...)
SET date=STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
SET time=UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE(@time, '%H:%i:%S.%f') )
```

The query works fine, apart from the last line (which throws SQLExceptions). I've tried different format patterns but am having problems working out the conversion from string to timestamp, before converting to unix timestamp. Google isn't helping either. I would really appreciate if anyone could suggest reasonable solution. Unfortunately, changing MySQL to other database is not an option.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

UNIX_TIMESTAMP wants a "date time" string - you're giving it a "time" string.

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE("01/11/2010", "%m/%d/%Y"), " ", STR_TO_DATE("10:00:00.577", "%H:%i:%S.%f")));
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it is sounds from the functional point of view. Unfortunately, the granularity of the timestamp was not saved and the resulting BIGINT holds only hours:minutes:seconds. Could anyone suggest a conversion that would be able to save the milisecond granularity?